# VMNet DHCP Server does not assign my Ubuntu machine its own IP

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vmware, dhcp

I am trying to build a Virtual Network in Ubuntu with two virtual machines who only have the means to communicate with each other independent of the host.

[image]

On *both* machines I went to Settings->Network Adapter and set to Custom (VMnet 2)

However I noticed after doing this one of my virtual machines (the ubuntu machine) - does not have it's own IP assigned by the DHCP server. It's 127.0.0.1

[image]

Why is there no 192.168.x.x IP assigned?

Comment: Your Host OS is?

Comment: @FranciscoTapia I am running VMWare Workstation on Windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `eth0` inteface
edit the following file

```
/etc/network/interfaces
```

and be sure it is configured as this:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Then be sure the VMNet 2 (Custom) is rightly configured:

> To change(check) DHCP settings:
>
> - Click Edit > Virtual Network Editor and select the virtual network adapter.

[image]

> - Select Use local DHCP service to distribute IP address to VMs and click DHCP settings.

[image]

> - Modify the third number in the IP address. For example, 192.168.x.0 or 198.16.x.0. In general, do not change the subnet mask. Certain
>     virtual network services might not work as well with a customized
>     subnet mask.

[image]

> - Click Apply.

[Source](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1018697)

---

[Aditional Resourses](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/Automatic)