# Can't statically assign IP to ubuntu VM

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine

I'm having the same problem as [this guy](https://superuser.com/questions/970463/vmnet-dhcp-server-does-not-assign-my-ubuntu-machine-its-own-ip) did and have researched for five hours today but am still without a solution.

In my VM I'm running Ubuntu 17.10. My host is Ubuntu 16.04.

I've edited the dhcp.conf file on my host to look like this:

```
host Ubuntu1 {
    hardware ethernet 00:0C:29:B6:22:3E;
    fixed-address  192.168.111.200;
}
```

In my VM interfaces I've edited it to be:

```
auto ens33
address 192.168.111.200
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.111.0
broadcast 192.168.111.255
gateway 192.168.1.254
post-up ethtool -K ens33 gro off
post-up ethtool -K ens33 lro off
```

Every time I reboot the VM, it takes away my interface "ens33" information so I have put the interface to UP every time.  But even when I do, it still doesn't give me an IP address.  I've assigned it to the custom vmnet2 virtual network which is where my dhcp.conf file was at.

All I want to do is set up Snort on this VM.  I want to have all network traffic come in through my home router, and then Snort will be the first thing it hits so it can act as an IPS.  Then after it hits this VM, I wanted it to go to another VM that I haven't set up yet, with PFSense on it, and then ultimately routed to my normal hosts on my network.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is confusing me, VirtualBox setup to run Host-Only networks doesn't generally use any external `dhcp.conf` to configure the DHCP server on the host. The configuration of the build-in DHCP server is done through the VirtualBox GUI. Are you saying you disabled the build-in DHCP server and run your own manually on the vboxnet0 interface?

Comment: Second, I would guess Ubuntu runs NetworkManager to manage connections by default and I would expect it to do so even on your guest, have you disabled it then? How exactly are you configuring the network on the guest? Is that through `/etc/network/interfaces` ?

Comment: Finally, the guy in linked question had different problem - he couldn't get the DHCP server to assign him dynamic IP. If you want static IPs, you don't need any DHCP server at all. Just find out what service, if any, is enabled on your guest system and use it to configure the static IP. For example enable `systemd-networkd` and use `/etc/systemd/network/*.network` files.

Comment: Thanks Marek.  I'm using VMWare Workstation.  I got the idea of editing the DHCP file on my host here: https://willwarren.com/2015/04/02/set-static-ip-address-in-vmware-fusion-7/
I also looked on page 171 of the vmware Guide and it told me to edit the dhcp server in order to statically assign an IP. I used the virtual netmgr in vmware earlier. I edited vmnet2 to have the correct subnet. Yes I configured the network on the vm in the interfaces file.  That is the paragraph above with all the IPs in it.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

1. Edited `/etc/networkmanager/networkmanager.conf` file and changed:

   ```
   managed = false
   ```

   to

   ```
   managed = true
   ```
2. Saved, then restarted the network-manager service:

   ```
   sudo service network-manager restart
   ```

This allowed the wired connection to become active and it reads the `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

Comment: Good work, glad you were able to figure it out!